# How to filter items when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a library where you can add books you've read or not read. I want to filter the books by read, not read and all, and displaying them when clicking on the correspondent button. When there's just one book in the library it works fine, but when I add more it either displays them all or none.

Here's the function that I used

```
    function filter(e) {
    const books = document.querySelectorAll(".book__container")
    if (e.target.classList.contains("all")) {
        books.forEach(book => {
            book.style.display = "flex";
        });
    } else if (e.target.classList.contains("read")) {
        books.forEach(book => {
            for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
                if(myLibrary[i].read) {
                    book.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    book.style.display = "none";
                } 
            }
        })
    } else if (e.target.classList.contains("not-read")) {
        books.forEach(book => {
            for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
                if (!myLibrary[i].read) {
                    book.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    book.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
}
```

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".add");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal__container");
const library = document.querySelector(".library__container");
const submitBook = document.querySelector(".add__book");
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector(".fas fa-trash-alt");
//Modal inputs
const modalTitle = document.querySelector("#title");
const modalAuthor = document.querySelector("#author");
const modalPages = document.querySelector("#pages");
const isRead = document.querySelector("#read-status");

//Toggle Modal
const hideModal = () => {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 };
 const showModal = () => {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    const cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");
    cancel.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        hideModal();
    });
 };
 addBtn.addEventListener("click", showModal);

let myLibrary = [];
let index = 0;

class Book {
    constructor(title, author, pages, read) {
        this.title = title,
            this.author = author,
            this.pages = pages,
            this.read = read;
    }
}


submitBook.addEventListener("click", addBookToLibrary);

function addBookToLibrary(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   let bookTitle = modalTitle.value;
   let bookAuthor = modalAuthor.value;
   let bookPages = modalPages.value;
   let bookStatus = isRead.checked;

   //Display error message if inputs are empty
   if (bookTitle === "" || bookAuthor === "" || bookPages === "") {
       const errorMessage = document.querySelector(".error__message--container");
       hideModal();
       errorMessage.style.display = "block";
       const errorBtn = document.querySelector(".error-btn");
       errorBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
           errorMessage.style.display = "none";
           showModal();
       })
   } else {
    let book = new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPages, bookStatus);
    myLibrary.push(book);
    
    hideModal();
    render();
}

function render() {
    library.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
        if(myLibrary[i].read){
        library.innerHTML += 
        '<div class="book__container">' +
        '<div class="book">' +
            '<div class="title__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Title : </span><span class="book__title">' +` ${myLibrary[i].title}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="author__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Author : </span><span class="book__author">'+` ${myLibrary[i].author}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="pages__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Pages : </span><span class="book__pages">'+` ${myLibrary[i].pages}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="book__read-elements">' +
                '<span class="book__read yes">I read it</span>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';
            
    } else {
    library.innerHTML += 
        '<div class="book__container">' +
        '<div class="book">' +
            '<div class="title__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Title : </span><span class="book__title">' +` ${myLibrary[i].title}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="author__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Author : </span><span class="book__author">'+` ${myLibrary[i].author}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="pages__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Pages : </span><span class="book__pages">'+` ${myLibrary[i].pages}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="book__read-elements">' +
                '<span class="book__read no">I have not read it</span>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

   }

   const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("i");
    buttons.forEach(button => {
       button.addEventListener("click", toggleBooks) 
    })
   function toggleBooks(e) {
        //Delete books
        const button = e.target;
        if (button.classList.contains("fa-trash-alt")) {
         button.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
         myLibrary.splice(button.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode, 1)
     }
     //Toggle read status
     if (button.classList.contains("fa-check")) {
         if (button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.classList.contains("no")) {
          button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.classList.toggle("yes");
          if (button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.textContent === "I have not read it") {
              button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.textContent = "I read it";
          } else {
              button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.textContent = "I have not read it"
          }
         } else {
          button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.classList.toggle("no");
         }
      }
    }

   }

   const filterBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-btn");
   filterBtn.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", filter) 
    })

    function filter(e) {
        const books = document.querySelectorAll(".book__container")
        if (e.target.classList.contains("all")) {
            books.forEach(book => {
                book.style.display = "flex";
            });
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains("read")) {
            books.forEach(book => {
                for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
                    if(myLibrary[i].read) {
                        book.style.display = "flex";
                    } else {
                        book.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                }
            })
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains("not-read")) {
            books.forEach(book => {
                for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
                    if (!myLibrary[i].read) {
                        book.style.display = "flex";
                    } else {
                        book.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        
    }
   

    modalTitle.value = "";
    modalAuthor.value = "";
    modalPages.value = "";
    isRead.checked = false;
   }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');
:root {
    --light-gray: #dededef3;
    --title-color: #333756;
    --main-color: #c6c6c6f3;

}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--light-gray);
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4rem;
    color: var(--title-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
button {
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: white;
    color: #333756;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.6s all ease;
}
:focus {
    /*outline: 1px solid white;*/
}

button:hover {
    background: var(--title-color);
    color: white;
}
.add__book:hover,
.cancel:hover {
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--title-color)
}
.filter-btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    background: var(--light-gray);
    border-bottom: 4px solid var(--title-color)
}
.library__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.book__container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 2rem 2rem;
}
.modal__container {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.book,
.modal {
    padding: 2rem 2rem;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #333756;
    line-height: 3rem;
}
.modal {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 8rem;
}
.modal__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
label {
    color: white;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
input {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.book__read-elements {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.main,
i {
    color: white;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}
.book__title,
.book__author,
.book__pages,
.book__read {
    color: var(--main-color)
}
.error__message--container {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.error__message--modal {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    width:40%;
}
.error {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(101, 3, 3);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgb(189, 96, 96);
    padding: 3rem 5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.error-btn {
    color: rgb(101, 3, 3);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.error-btn:hover {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(101, 3, 3);
}
.no {
    color:rgb(194, 89, 89)
}
.yes {
    color:rgb(110, 176, 120)
}
footer {
    height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--title-color)
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>My Library</h1>
        <button class="add">Add New Book</button>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="filter-btn all" data-filter="all">View All</button>
            <button class="filter-btn read" data-filter="read">Read</button>
            <button class="filter-btn not-read" data-filter="not-read">Not Read</button>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="error__message--container">
        <div class="error__message--modal">
            <div class="error">
                <p>Complete the form!</p>
                <button class ="error-btn">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal-->
    <form class="modal__container">
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal__content">
                <label for="">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title"> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal__content">
                <label for="">Author:</label>
                <input type="text" id="author">
            </div>
            <div class="modal__content">
                <label for="">Pages:</label>
                <input type="number" id="pages">
            </div>
            <div>
            <label for="read-status">Check the box if you've read this book</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="read-status" value ="check">
            </div>
            
            <button class="add__book">Add</button>
            <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!--End of Modal-->
    <div class="library__container"></div>
    <footer>
        <p>from <a href="https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/javascript/lessons/library">The Odin Project</a> - by <a href="https://github.com/TamaraNC/library">TamaraNC</a></p>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it intended that in your `Book` `constructor` you use comma instead of semicolon?

Comment: In your `books.foreach(book` to get your read state of that book: `var read = book.querySelector('.book__read-elements .book__read).classList.contains('yes');`
Then you can use that `read` variable to determine if you show the book or not: `if(read)` or `if(!read)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things were a bit off with your code. First off you used a `for` loop to loop through the books, but had no way to refer which book it was in relation to the `books` variable. This caused the last item in your `myLibrary` array to determine the visibility for all books. Second thing was you didn't get the actual read value from the book html which you were iterating:

```
function filter(e) {
        const books = document.querySelectorAll(".book__container")
        if (e.target.classList.contains("all")) {
            books.forEach(book => {
                book.style.display = "flex";
            });
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains("read")) {
            books.forEach(book => {
                var read = book.querySelector('.book__read-elements .book__read').classList.contains('yes');//get the read value from html
                if(read){
                    book.style.display = "flex";
                }else{
                    book.style.display = "none";
                }
            })
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains("not-read")) {
            books.forEach(book => {
                var read = book.querySelector('.book__read-elements .book__read').classList.contains('yes');//get the read value from html
                if(!read){
                    book.style.display = "flex";
                }else{
                    book.style.display = "none";
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do just 2 things

1. Add `read` class to the `book-container` whose `read` checkbox is checked `if(myLibrary[i].read){` inside this add `read` class to the html that is being constructed
2. Don't loop again with `myLibrary` array. Just use `book` to check whether it contains `read` class or not. Based on that you can display the book or hide the book

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".add");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal__container");
const library = document.querySelector(".library__container");
const submitBook = document.querySelector(".add__book");
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector(".fas fa-trash-alt");
//Modal inputs
const modalTitle = document.querySelector("#title");
const modalAuthor = document.querySelector("#author");
const modalPages = document.querySelector("#pages");
const isRead = document.querySelector("#read-status");

//Toggle Modal
const hideModal = () => {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 };
 const showModal = () => {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    const cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");
    cancel.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        hideModal();
    });
 };
 addBtn.addEventListener("click", showModal);

let myLibrary = [];
let index = 0;

class Book {
    constructor(title, author, pages, read) {
        this.title = title,
            this.author = author,
            this.pages = pages,
            this.read = read;
    }
}


submitBook.addEventListener("click", addBookToLibrary);

function addBookToLibrary(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   let bookTitle = modalTitle.value;
   let bookAuthor = modalAuthor.value;
   let bookPages = modalPages.value;
   let bookStatus = isRead.checked;

   //Display error message if inputs are empty
   if (bookTitle === "" || bookAuthor === "" || bookPages === "") {
       const errorMessage = document.querySelector(".error__message--container");
       hideModal();
       errorMessage.style.display = "block";
       const errorBtn = document.querySelector(".error-btn");
       errorBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
           errorMessage.style.display = "none";
           showModal();
       })
   } else {
    let book = new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPages, bookStatus);
    myLibrary.push(book);
    
    hideModal();
    render();
}

function render() {
    library.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
        if(myLibrary[i].read){
        library.innerHTML += 
        '<div class="book__container read">' +
        '<div class="book">' +
            '<div class="title__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Title : </span><span class="book__title">' +` ${myLibrary[i].title}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="author__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Author : </span><span class="book__author">'+` ${myLibrary[i].author}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="pages__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Pages : </span><span class="book__pages">'+` ${myLibrary[i].pages}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="book__read-elements">' +
                '<span class="book__read yes">I read it</span>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';
            
    } else {
    library.innerHTML += 
        '<div class="book__container">' +
        '<div class="book">' +
            '<div class="title__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Title : </span><span class="book__title">' +` ${myLibrary[i].title}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="author__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Author : </span><span class="book__author">'+` ${myLibrary[i].author}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="pages__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Pages : </span><span class="book__pages">'+` ${myLibrary[i].pages}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="book__read-elements">' +
                '<span class="book__read no">I have not read it</span>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

   }

   const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("i");
    buttons.forEach(button => {
       button.addEventListener("click", toggleBooks) 
    })
   function toggleBooks(e) {
        //Delete books
        const button = e.target;
        if (button.classList.contains("fa-trash-alt")) {
         button.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
         myLibrary.splice(button.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode, 1)
     }
     //Toggle read status
     if (button.classList.contains("fa-check")) {
         if (button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.classList.contains("no")) {
          button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.classList.toggle("yes");
          if (button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.textContent === "I have not read it") {
              button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.textContent = "I read it";
          } else {
              button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.textContent = "I have not read it"
          }
         } else {
          button.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.classList.toggle("no");
         }
      }
    }

   }

   const filterBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-btn");
   filterBtn.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", filter) 
    })

    function filter(e) {
        const books = document.querySelectorAll(".book__container")
        if (e.target.classList.contains("all")) {
            books.forEach(book => {
                book.style.display = "flex";
            });
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains("read")) {
            books.forEach(book => {
                if(book.classList.contains('read')) {
                  book.style.display = 'flex';
                } else {
                  book.style.display = 'none';
                }
            })
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains("not-read")) {
            books.forEach(book => {
                if(!book.classList.contains('read')) {
                  book.style.display = 'flex';
                } else {
                  book.style.display = 'none';
                }
            })
        }
        
    }
   

    modalTitle.value = "";
    modalAuthor.value = "";
    modalPages.value = "";
    isRead.checked = false;
   }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');
:root {
    --light-gray: #dededef3;
    --title-color: #333756;
    --main-color: #c6c6c6f3;

}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--light-gray);
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4rem;
    color: var(--title-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
button {
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: white;
    color: #333756;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.6s all ease;
}
:focus {
    /*outline: 1px solid white;*/
}

button:hover {
    background: var(--title-color);
    color: white;
}
.add__book:hover,
.cancel:hover {
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--title-color)
}
.filter-btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    background: var(--light-gray);
    border-bottom: 4px solid var(--title-color)
}
.library__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.book__container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 2rem 2rem;
}
.modal__container {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.book,
.modal {
    padding: 2rem 2rem;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #333756;
    line-height: 3rem;
}
.modal {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 8rem;
}
.modal__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
label {
    color: white;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
input {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.book__read-elements {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.main,
i {
    color: white;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}
.book__title,
.book__author,
.book__pages,
.book__read {
    color: var(--main-color)
}
.error__message--container {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.error__message--modal {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    width:40%;
}
.error {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(101, 3, 3);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgb(189, 96, 96);
    padding: 3rem 5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.error-btn {
    color: rgb(101, 3, 3);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.error-btn:hover {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(101, 3, 3);
}
.no {
    color:rgb(194, 89, 89)
}
.yes {
    color:rgb(110, 176, 120)
}
footer {
    height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--title-color)
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>My Library</h1>
        <button class="add">Add New Book</button>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="filter-btn all" data-filter="all">View All</button>
            <button class="filter-btn read" data-filter="read">Read</button>
            <button class="filter-btn not-read" data-filter="not-read">Not Read</button>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="error__message--container">
        <div class="error__message--modal">
            <div class="error">
                <p>Complete the form!</p>
                <button class ="error-btn">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal-->
    <form class="modal__container">
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal__content">
                <label for="">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title"> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal__content">
                <label for="">Author:</label>
                <input type="text" id="author">
            </div>
            <div class="modal__content">
                <label for="">Pages:</label>
                <input type="number" id="pages">
            </div>
            <div>
            <label for="read-status">Check the box if you've read this book</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="read-status" value ="check">
            </div>
            
            <button class="add__book">Add</button>
            <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!--End of Modal-->
    <div class="library__container"></div>
    <footer>
        <p>from <a href="https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/javascript/lessons/library">The Odin Project</a> - by <a href="https://github.com/TamaraNC/library">TamaraNC</a></p>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, that for loop is unnecessary in the filter function. +1

Comment: In the javascript which generates the book html, the correct class name is `yes` or `no` which is given to `.book__read-elements .book__read` element. You should edit the answer to correspond to that structure.